# React Card not performant (stuttered loading)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

On my portfolio site I have these cards that on hover expand and give a description of the project ([visual here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BYgcBG9rm4zcN-E9Nr9FHX6P3227Fu9-/view?usp=sharing)). The issue is , these cards are not perfomant when first loading them in [as in here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16gJBZi7Fope_IgrUpfZvyNS8mLKBxCxt/view?usp=sharing) (the sudden jump up is because of the stutter, I was scrolling up the whole time and sometimes its really bad as in takes a good 2-3 seconds to load in).

Here is the card.js

```js
import React from "react";
import './App.css';



const Card = (props) => {

    const divStyle = {
        backgroundImage: `url("${props.image}")`,
      };

    return ( 
        
        <div class="link-card" style={divStyle}>
    <a class = "test" href= {props.href} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    
    <div class="textbox-name">
                <h2>
                    <div class="textbody-name">
                        {props.name}
                        
                    </div>
                </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="textbox-desc">
                <h4>
                    <div class="textbody-desc">
                        {props.body}
                        
                    </div>
                </h4>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
     );
}
 
export default Card;
```

and the Css used to control the animation

```css
/* Box */

/* Overarching container for everything */
.link-card {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;

  /* background-image:url('./assets/plan-or-to-do-list-concept-with-hand-drawn-text-checklist-task-list-illustration-in-flat-cartoon-style-on-white-background-vector.jpeg'); */
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  
  width: 50vw;
  height: 11vh;
  
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 2px 4px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* border: 1px green solid; */
}

/* How the entire container should act on mouse over */
.link-card:hover {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;

  background-size: 200%;
  background-position: center;

  width: 55vw;

  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 2px 4px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}




/* The Colour Fade Box Ontop (the orangish tint on top)*/
.link-card > a {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding: 1.3rem 1.3rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(226, 109, 92, 0.716);

  /* border: 1px white solid; */
  /* border: 1px green solid; */
}

/* How the Colour Fade Box Ontop (the orangish tint on top) should act on mouse hover*/
.link-card:hover > a {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: rgba(226, 109, 92, 0.916);

  /* border: 1px white solid; */
  /* border: 1px green solid; */
}

/* The decription of the project that pops up on mouse hover */
.test > .textbox-desc{
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0%;
  /* background-color: black; */
}

/* The name of the project */
.textbody-name{
  color:black;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: dogicapixel;
}

.textbody-desc{
  font-family: dogicapixel;
}

.test > .textbox-name{
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration:none;
  
  position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 100%;
}


.test:hover > .textbox-name{
  height: 25%;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0%;

}
.test:hover > .textbox-desc{
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 100%;
  
}
```

I did notice that the performance issues started happening after I laid over the dark orangish tint (the way I did that I admit was indeed very messy) , so it would be awesome if someone could point out what im doing wrong or give a better way of adding the tint so that it animates along with the card.